# Dynamic Conversion Value Implementation

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a limited knowledge on this setting up these things. Can someone help me out?    Is there a way to set this up via Javascript. It is on a ASP.net website.

Google Analytics Conversion Tag

```
<!-- Google Analytics Conversion Tag -->                                                                                                     
<script type="text/javascript">           
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 91022;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "PaHSymHsgM";
var google_conversion_value = subtotal;
var google_conversion_currency = "USD";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript><img height=1 width=1 border=0
       src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/930232/? value=subtotal&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;label=PaHSCOPJfM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you implement the conversion tracking via Google Tag Manager(GTM).
You can use something called the [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) to track all the conversion variables.

In GTM, you can create references to DataLayer variables and track these conversion variables. Then you can add a "Google Ads Conversion Tracking" tag. This is the same as you adding the conversion tag manually on your pages. From there you can fill in all the fields required to track the conversion: Conversion ID, Conversion Label, Conversion Value, Order ID, Currency Code, etc.

[Here's a good write up as well.](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2018/01/30/guide-adwords-conversion-tracking-2018/)